# Button click renders multiple unwanted components React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is this: I have a component that must be rendered 3 times in the app, and the component has a button which ***should*** update the component with a new component. I'm getting the placeholder component in each instance instead of just the component that triggered the event. My code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {showCard : false,cards : []}
    this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this)
  }

  buttonClick(ev){
    console.log(ev.target)
    const nextId = this.state.cards.length + 1
    this.setState({cards: this.state.cards.concat([nextId])})
    this.setState({showCard: true,})
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>React Demo</h2>
          <ul className="container">
            <Contact key="0" text={"Contact 1"} buttonClick={this.buttonClick} showCard={this.state.showCard} cards={this.state.cards}/>
            <Contact key="1" text={"Contact 2"} buttonClick={this.buttonClick} showCard={this.state.showCard} cards={this.state.cards}/>
            <Contact key="2" text={"Contact 3"} buttonClick={this.buttonClick} showCard={this.state.showCard} cards={this.state.cards}/>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Contact(props){
    return <li>
            <h3>{props.text}</h3>
            <ul className="stack">
              <li><button id={props.text} type="button" className="block" onClick={e =>props.buttonClick(e)}>+</button></li>
              {props.cards.map(cardId => <Card key={props.text+cardId}/>)}
            </ul>
           </li>
}

function Card(){
  return <li><div className="card">Place Holder</div></li>
}

export default App;
```

I have tried conditional rendering with `showCard` and mapping as seen here, in both cases all three of instances of the component are updated instead of the correct one. I know it's something stupid I'm doing, I just can't see it. Thanks in advance.

J

Comment: You are sharing the `state.cards` from your app with each of the instances, so no wonder you get the same in each. You might want to divide them up somehow so that each instance has its own set of cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code:

```
const list = [
  {
    id : 0,
    title : "Contact 1",
    showCard : false,
    addCard : ()=> <Card key={"x"+count++}/>,
    cards : []
  },
  {
    id : 1,
    title : "Contact 2",
    showCard : false,
    addCard : ()=> <Card key={"y"+count++}/>,
    cards : []
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    title : "Contact 3",
    showCard : false,
    addCard : ()=> <Card key={"z"+count++}/>,
    cards : []
   }
]


let count = 0

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {list : list}
    this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this)
  }

  buttonClick(ev,id){
    let a0 = null
    for(let obj of this.state.list){
      if(obj.id === id){ 
        a0 = obj.addCard()
        obj.cards.push(a0)
      }
    }
    this.setState({list:this.state.list})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>React Demo</h2>
          <ul className="container">
            {this.state.list.map((item) =>
                <Contact key={item.title+item.id} text={item.title} buttonClick={this.buttonClick} showCard={item.showCard} id={item.id} cards={item.cards}/>
          )}

        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Contact(props){
    return <li>
            <h3>{props.text}</h3>
            <ul className="stack">
              <li><button id={props.text} type="button" className="block" onClick={e =>props.buttonClick(e,props.id)}>+</button></li>
              {props.cards.map((card)=> {
                return card || null
                })}
            </ul>
           </li>
}

function Card(){
  return <li><div className="card">Place Holder</div></li>
}

export default App;
```

As Jonas H ***suggested*** I was sharing state with all three instances of the Contact component. I've only been doing React for a couple of weeks hence the time it took to solve this. My solution may not be optimal, but it works, although it did break my UI... but that's another mission. Thanks to all.

J

Thanks to @Jonas H

Answer (score -2):

**shouldComponentUpdate()** method will solve your problem

Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior. [more](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   // should return either true or fase 

   // component should render on state changes or initial render
   if((JSON.stringify(nextState) !== JSON.stringify(this.state)) || (JSON.stringify(this.state) === (JSON.stringify({showCard : false,cards : []})) ) {
     return true;
   }

     return false;
}
```

put above method to your code

Comment: How will this prevent the cards from `state.cards` showing up in each instance and instead only show in the instance the button was clicked?